# Front Camera Not Working, Showing HARDWARE_LEVEL_LIMITED

Tags: hardware, lg, front-camera

I had to replace the screen on my Lg V20 and broke the front and wide angle camera while doing so. When I ordered replacements and replaced them, the wide angle worked, but now the front camera crashes both the LG camera and Google Camera port. When I scanned it with a Camera2 API scanner, it showed up, but I noticed it said HARDWARE_LEVEL_LIMITED next to hardware level. Is there anything I can do to get this working?

Comment: did you replaced the hardware in authorized service center or in a local repairing shop?

Comment: @parthu_panther I replaced everything myself using parts from fixez.com

Comment: than it might be the case that you replaced the new hardware of higher version than your phone could have supported.

Comment: @parthu_panther I have a V20 and I bought the parts for the V20. The wide angle camera worked and the connectors were the same.

Comment: as you stated in your post that 'when you scanned it with camera2 API scanner, it showed up'. That means your software config are fine. I think you should show your device at a trusty hardware repairing center.